# calculating probability of profit

Tags: probability

lets say I rent out a car. The car cost me 100\$ to buy and no other costs are involved. When I rent out the car I make 50\$ a month. The car might break down and I cannot fix it after that so what profit I make when the car breaks is the total profit on that car.

As an example, from previous experience I know that the probability of this car breaking before discrete points in time. 1 month  = 20%, 2 months = 40%, 3 months = 50%, 4 months = 60%, etc.

How would I do the calculation on my expected profit from this? As an added question, I have only ever owned a car for less than 7 months, after that I might have sold it so I do not know the probability after this. Can i still find some total expected profit somehow?

Comment: How much did you sell your six/seven month old car for?

Comment: Sell was a bad choice, what I meant was that it did not break down so it does not change any of the probabilities. So lets say I gave it away for 0\$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: yes sorry I have, I just cannot find anywhere to start. My first though was to add up the expected profit for each discrete interval but that broke down when i got to the break even point since 50% of 0 is still 0. If anyone could point me in the right direction towards similar calculations that would be great! I had to change the actual problem into this car scenario due to reasons.

Comment: The actual problem is that I have a machine learning model that gives me a probability of an event before some point in time. From that I want to find the expected profit given these probabilities. What I can find is the probability that the car breaks before break-even but that still leaves out a lot of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to find the probability the car stops earning after a given number of months, perhaps (if I have read your description of the probabilities correctly)

```
months cum.prob prob
  1      0.2     0.2
  2      0.4     0.2
  3      0.5     0.1
  4      0.6     0.1
  5      0.7     0.1
  6      0.8     0.1
  7      1.0     0.2
```

so the expected number of months earning: $$1 \times 0.2+2 \times 0.2 +3 \times 0.1 +4 \times 0.1 +5 \times 0.1 +6 \times 0.1 +7 \times 0.2 =3.8$$

and thus an expected net profit of $$\$50 \times 3.8 - \$100= \$90$$

Comment: Good idea to consider expected number of months. I still feel like it is still not really correct since each month interval is not independent. Maybe using the cumulative prob is better? 1 * 0.8 + 2 * 0.6 + 3 * 0.5 + 4 * 0.4 etc? I cant really wrap my head around this..

Comment: @Jarnald If you want to use the survival probabilities that way, then try $1+0.8+0.6+0.5+0.4+0.3+0.2+0=3.8$ (not a coincidence)

Comment: Yep thinking about it some more I managed to get it straight in my head. Thank you!

Comment: For the added question, lets say we know that at month 6 the cumulative prob is 0.8. I have no more data and the car might continue to run indefinitely. Can we still use the remaining 0.2 to somehow approximate how long it will run after that? I feel like it is not possible unless we assume how the cum.prob will continue to increase.

Comment: @Jarnald If the car has a positive probability of running forever and you do not discount future cash flows, then the expected profit will be infinite